# Sending extra param value via select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My View:

```
<%= form_tag(update_user_products_path, :id => "update_user_form") do %>
<%@products.each do |product| %>
            <div class = "prod">
            <a href='<%= recommendations_path(:product_id => product.id, :rating_set_id => params[:rating_set_id]) %>' target="_blank"><img src='<%= product.cover_img %>' class='product_image_prods'></img></a>
            <div class= "title"><small><b><%= link_to truncate(product.title, :length =>30),  recommendations_path(:product_id => product.id, :rating_set_id => params[:rating_set_id]), :target => '_blank' %></b></small></div>
            <br/>
            <div><em>Current Rating: <%= product.rating %> </em></div>
            <%= select_tag "user_id:#{product.id}", options_for_select(User.all.collect {|u| [ u.name, u.id ] })%>
            </div>
            <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

I need to send 2 params to my controller update action -- product.id of each record and user.id for the selected record. Calling params.keys returns:

```
utf8
authenticity_token
user_id:1
user_id:2
user_id:3
user_id:4
...
user_id:78
commit
action
controller
```

I an able to split params.keys by (":"). Doing this returns the same output as params.keys. Is there another way to pass product.id to my update_user action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the name of the select to

```
<%= select_tag :user_id, options_for_select(User.all.collect {|u| [ u.name, u.id ] }), name: "users[#{product.id}]" %>
```

which will give you a hash for `params[:users]` where the keys are the product_ids and the values are the user_ids

Comment: can you post that in another question? be sure to include the controller code :)

Comment: I figured it out :). I had to iterate through the product_ids and user_ids; my method was initially only iterating through the product_ids. Thank you very much!